# Perform operation on specific column in filtered range, right after filtering

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have this formula in E2: `=FILTER(A1:C20,B1:B20=2)` and need to perform substitute like:

[image: 1]

[spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GMXdSMlti4mxXJmpMPamveqwmu148FZz_MTLm2m9Cno/edit?usp=sharing)

I'm hoping to do the formula in a single cell, without additional columns.

Comment: next time pls ask properly

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. I should emphasize that I only want to substitute things in a specific column. I have edited the spreadsheet and your answer don't work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER({A1:B, SUBSTITUTE(C1:C, "stuff", "blah")}, B1:B=2))
```

[image: 5]

Comment: Thank you MMA, you've been a great help around here!

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(A1:C20, B1:B20=2), "stuff", "blah"))
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. I should emphasize that I only want to substitute things in a specific column. I have edited the spreadsheet and your answer don't work anymore.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ylwZvj4

Comment: @AllenSierra I see, added new answer